# I need a wordpress hook that can replace [...] in excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, hook

I need a wordpress hook that can replace [...] in excerpt.

```
function mytheme_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
  return 15;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'mytheme_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I think the question is super clear for those who have worked with WordPress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter you are using is to set excerpt length. To replace the `[...]` at the end of excerpt, [excerpt_more](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/excerpt_more/) filter is used. Here is how you can change it to `(more)`.

```
function mytheme_excerpt_more($more) {

  $more = sprintf( '<a class="read-more" href="%1$s">%2$s</a>', get_permalink( get_the_ID() ), esc_html__( '(more)', 'mytheme' ) );

  return $more;

}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'mytheme_excerpt_more');
```